# Database connection for ASP.NET CORE on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, asp.net-core

**OS Ubuntu 16.04.**

I have an **ASP.NET Core** application with **SQL Server Express** as database server

So, I'm trying migrate database:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

Command was successful.

```
dotnet ef database update
```

This command returns error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>
> The server was not found or was not accessible.
>
> Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
> (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 44 - Could not compose Service Principal Name (SPN) for Windows Integrated Authentication. Possible causes are server(s) incorrectly specified to connection API calls, Domain Name System (DNS) lookup failure or memory shortage)

Connection string:

```
Server=(localhost)\\sqlexpress;Database=SOME_DB;User Id=sa;Password=SOME_PASS;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

Since I can connect to db server from Rider I assume that db server is working correctly.

Comment: Are you using docker?

Comment: @AmiNadimi, no.

Comment: `(localhost)` is invalid. `(local)` means the local machine when working with Named Pipes. `localhost` is the name of the local machine when working with TCP/IP. Use `localhost\\sqlexpress.` Of course, this assumes you *have* installed SQL Server Express on the local machine. If you want to connect to another machine, use *the other machine's IP/name*

Comment: are you developing on linux? if yes, what is your IDE? if not and your developement environment is linux, what web server are you using?